# how to find textbox value from asp.net to javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

i have a textbox in asp.net form.... if i entered numbers not like 7 or 8 or 9, then script function should be araised with alert message.... how to achieve this.... that 7 or 8 or 9 are first digits in my  texbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
var testValue = document.getelementbyid('<%= TEXT_BOX.ClientID %>').value;
var re = new RegExp('/^[7-9]/');
if (testValue.match(re))
    // SUCCESS
else
    // NO SUCCESS
```

Better solution is usage of RegexValidator with Regex `/^[7-9]/` or something like that.
It will generate javascript code automatically

Comment: ClientId - id of your textbox on the page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: ok.. thanks.. only scripting , no validation controls... thats why i am trying on this

Comment: mobile no series should be start with 7 or 8 or 9... from 2nd digit also we can enter 7 or 8 or 9... isnt it. my question is , if the first digit is either 7, 8 or 9 then allow to enter another keycode.. if not alert('enter a valid mobile series')

Comment: ya i used like this... testValue = document.getelementbyid('<%= TEXT_BOX.ClientID %>').value.charat(0); if(testvalue!=7 && testvalue!=8 && testvalue!=9) { alert('yes'); }else alert('no'); }